# Spring MVC - Basic RequestMapping question

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring MVC. I'm getting errors on the following (not sure yet what;s the full scope of info requierd to assist me):

Working fine:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "startpage.do")
 public ModelAndView startpage(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
.
.
  ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("startpage");
  mv.getModelMap().addAttribute("loginPage", loginPage);
  return mv;
```

But failing:

```
         @RequestMapping(value = "somecontroller.do")
 public ModelAndView ftcontroller(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, ModelAndView mav) {.. ...
   ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("startpage");
      mv.getModelMap().addAttribute("loginPage", loginPage);
  return mav;
```

As you can see, same code, different request mapping. Could it be that this is consuing the MVC somehow to get confused?

The error I'm getting is:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
 at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp.__somecontroller._jspService(__ftcontroller.java:103)
 at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
 Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

The biz logic is a login screen "startpage.do" when Login is submitted, it can fail (in which case, startup.do should be retuend once again, in other case, a differn page should be returned.

if there is better way to implement this, I'll be happy to hear that.

(It should be noted that I'm trying to plug-in Spring MVC into an existing project, so I'm trying to make as little as possible changes, and hence not using spring:form etc..)

More info:

1. The JSP startpage.jsp (resolved from "startpage") has a form with target="somecontroller.do".
2. Full controller code:

   class
   {
       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "startpage.do")
   public ModelAndView startpage(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
       System.out.println(">>>>>>HomeController: Passing through (Get Type)...");
       LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage();
       ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("startpage");
       mv.getModelMap().addAttribute("loginPage", loginPage);
       return mv;
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "somecontroller.do")
   public ModelAndView ftcontroller(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
           throws Exception {

       // Parsing for login request;
       String sUsername = req.getParameter(USER_ID);
       String sUserPassword = req.getParameter(PASSWORD);
       AbstractResponseDataComponent returnedResponse = new LoginCommand().login(sUsername, sUserPassword);

       String returnedView = GlobalConstants.EMPTY_STRING;
       JstlView view = new JstlView();
       Map model = new HashMap();
       if (returnedResponse.isSuccessful()) 
       {
           view.setUrl("somecontroller");
           model.put("loginResponse", (LoginResponse) returnedResponse);

       } else 
       {
           view.setUrl("startpage");
           model.put("loginPage", (LoginPage) returnedResponse);
       }
       return new ModelAndView(view, model);

   }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: If you're getting errors, tell us what they are.

Comment: @user569544: This doesn't look like a mapping problem. What is the `loginPage` variable referring to, and are you referring to it in your JSP?

Comment: Yes, I'm reffering to it in the JSP, it's a class that is part of a larger application some information related to the login process.

Comment: @user569544: You didn't tell me where `loginPage` is defined.  Can we see the whole controller class, and not just the methods?

Comment: Which Spring Version do you use?

Comment: Try to remove the reponse parameter from your handler method, it seams that you do not use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW: when using Spring 3.0 make your method signature more clean:

instead of

```
public ModelAndView ftcontroller(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws Exception {
  String sUsername = req.getParameter(USER_ID);
  String sUserPassword = req.getParameter(PASSWORD);
...
```

do it in the spring 3.0 way:

```
public ModelAndView ftcontroller(
   @RequestParam(USER_ID) String sUsername, 
   @RequestParam(PASSWORD) String sUserPassword)
    throws Exception {

...
```

Comment: **maybe this is the cause** - I am not 100% sure but "returning" a HttpServletResponse and a View could Spring made mad.

Comment: I'm now getting Error 400--Bad Request, after I changed the method signature to:{ 
public ModelAndView ftcontroller( @RequestParam(SecurityConstants.USER_ID) String sUserId, @RequestParam(SecurityConstants.PASSWORD) String sPassword, @RequestParam(SecurityConstants.AUTH_TYPE) String sAuthType)}

Comment: Did you submitted all 3 parameter?

Comment: You can try in a first step to remove only the response parameter!

Comment: Did so and it seemed to have fixed the problem. There seem to have multiple issues impacting Spring MVC consistency in requestmapping, I'm still unable to get this working when i return ModelAndView, only if I take Model as a parameter and return String as the view name. very odd and discouraging. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: When returning ModelAndView, how did you set the view: per simple string or per JstlView?

Comment: I tried to either return a ModelAndView (failed) or a String (works fine after the response parameter was removed). It also failes (error 400) when I add the @RequestParam to the signature of the method.

Comment: Again: When returning ModelAndView, **how did you set the view in ModelAndView: per simple string or per JstlView?** - And you need the remove the Response Parameter of course too)

Answer (score 1):

For your second question:

> if there is better way to implement
>   this, I'll be happy to hear that.

Are you looking for something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "startpage.do")
public String startpage() {
    ...    
    if (loginFailed) {
       return "redirect:startpage.do");
    } else {
       return "redirect:somecontroller.do");
    }
}
```

(I prefere redirects, because I assume the that login methods has some sideeffects.)

Comment: But the method handling startpage.do or somecontroleler.do (based on sucess of login) might require a Model content, how do I go about passing this?

Comment: There is no need to redirect to the same page, you can simply return the same view.

Comment: @user569544 - then add the paramter to the method

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little bit confused, I updated my full controller code in the question. To better explain this, what I'm looking for is how to handle a login page that can also show erros from a previously failed attempt or, a route to successfull login, a route tht will transfer the loginResponse object to the success jsp.

Comment: @axtavt: of course - in case of loginFailed would returning only the view the better choise, wenn login passed the redirect is more cleaner (think of stuff like Browser-Back-Button). -- But at least I made my answer is this way, to make more clean of what I suggest: making the choise in the controller but not in the jsp.

Answer (score 0):

I belive the cause of your exception is the JstlView.

Try not to use the JstlView direct, instad pass the view name as String.

```
final String viewName;
Map model = new HashMap();
if (returnedResponse.isSuccessful()) 
{
    viewName = "somecontroller";
    model.put("loginResponse", (LoginResponse) returnedResponse);

} else 
{
    viewName = "startpage";
    model.put("loginPage", (LoginPage) returnedResponse);
}
return new ModelAndView(viewName, model);
```

Comment: I tried that as well, it it didn't work. for a reason I'm still not understand even when login is failing, and returned viewname is "startpage", the MVC is routing to "somecontroller", I'm struggling to understand why.

Comment: Did you put this logic in the correct controller method (the one that is invoked when the login form response is send to the server)?

Comment: Yes. he login action is "somecontroller.do", and I added this into the method mapped to "somecontroller.do". Also when debugging this, I see that the view is defined as "startpage", still, "somecontroller" is the one displayed, and I a not sure why or how to trace what is going on in the MVC guts.

Comment: @user569544: i do not realy understand you last post: the form submit "somecontroller.do", ftcontroller is invoked, and it returns with viewName = "somecontroller";
--- is this correct?

Comment: Should have been: action of the form in "startpage.jsp" is "somecontroller.do", so the method mapped to "somcontroller.do" is invoked. but when I return view of name "startpage", still the jsp resolved is "somecontroller.jsp". I hope this makes some sense.

Comment: Did you CHECKED that returnedResponse.isSuccessful() is realy true, (by some logging or system.out for example))!

Comment: Yes. But the problem is when isSuccesful is False, I'm for some reason being redirected to the somecontroller page. is there a good way to make Spring MVC log it's resolving path?